# Getting Windows Controls from a different Windows Forms File

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

How would I get a control from a different windows form.

Like Say I have a windows form (Form2) that I just want it to show when its doing a process in the main form (Like generating a file). Form 2 has a progress bar but I need to access controls from form1 to correctly make the progressbar progress how I want it to.

I have a Treeview in form1 and I want the progressbar value (Increment value) to go up a certain percent when a timer ticks. so it would get the total amount of nodes in the treeview on form1 and divide that into 100 and set that as interval.

I know in visual basic all you have to do is form1.Controlname.Restofcode

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe of many of the questions you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=access+form+controls+from+different+form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest (but not necessarily the best) way to do this is to:

1. Store a reference in the `Form1` to the `Form2` and vice-verse.
2. Change the `Modifiers` property in the designer of the controls you need access to to "Public".

For example, in your `Form2`:

```
public Form1 myForm1;
```

Then, when creating your `Form2` from the `Form1`:

```
Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();
myForm2.myForm1 = this;
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. I created the Form2 by using Add windows form in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @DarkWolfModding When I say "create" I don't mean when you create it in the designer, I mean when your code is creating it for the purpose of it existing and being shown to the user. Please edit your question to show the code you are using to create your `Form2`.

Comment: I just used the designer to create the form.

Comment: @DarkWolfModding You're not hearing me. I am not talking about when you created the form in the designer. In order for you to be showing the form to a user, you have to create an instance of it somewhere in your code.

Comment: I did a form2.show; with a defined variable of form2

Comment: @DarkWolfModding Ok, so within the code for Form2, you add that first code line from my answer. Then, right before you call Form2.Show(), you use the second bit of code from my answer.